# How can a count if else statement be written as a mathematical formula?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, piecewise-continuity

I want to express the following statement as a formula:

All probability values of $max(x,y)$ should be counted if and only if they have reached a certain boundary value, otherwise the value will not be counted. So only valid values should be counted. For example, I have the values 
 \begin{matrix}
  2 & 3 \\
  4 & 4 \\
  5 & 1
 \end{matrix}
and a boundary of [4], than the output should be 66,7% since on first row neither 2 or 3 is >= 4.

My approach with piecewise function:

\begin{equation}
Coverage = \sum^n_{i=1} 
    \begin{cases}
        \max(P(x^{(i)}), P(x^{(j)}) & \text{if} & P(x^{(i)}) \lor P(x^{(j)}) \geq t\in[0.5...0.95] \\
        0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases} 
\end{equation}

Is this formula correct and how can it be improved?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function):
$$H[x]=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1 & \text{if }x\geq 0\\0&\text{if }x<0\end{array}\right..$$

Then you want to say something like

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \max\{P(x),P(y)\}H[\max\{x,y\}-4]$$

Comment: To be honest, I didn't understand where the $P$ comes from in your example or what you mean by "all probability values should be counted". I hope this works?